# How to right this curl command in Python

Tags: python-3.x, url, curl, request

I have a curl command that I want to write in python. I am new to python so I don't know which packages, or setup to use. Any ideas or suggestions?'

This is my curl command:

```
curl -k https://localhost:8089 --data-urlencode username=admin --data-urlencode password=pass
```

Here is what i have so far in python:

```
baseurl = 'https://localhost:8089'
username = 'my_user'
password = 'my_pass'
```

Anything would help!

Comment: use `subprocess.run`, or the python curl module.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick below. Definitely check out the requests module [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for more information.

```
import requests

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
base_url = 'https://localhost:8089'

r = request.get(base_url, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
```